# Parse date using lubridate in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to parse date format like "Apr-13", "May-14", which I want to parse it to POSIX time "2013-04-01 UTC", "2014-05-01 UTC". I tried using `lubridate` package in R:

```
parse_date_time("Apr-13", "my")
parse_date_time("Apr-13", "by")
parse_date_time("Apr-13", "%b-%y")
parse_date_time("Apr-13", "%m-%y")
fast_strptime("Apr-13", "%b-%y")
```

But all of them failed to parse, is it possible to parse this using `lubridate`? Any other package is also welcome.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using the yearmon class in pkg:zoo since you do not really have dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this example:

```
library(lubridate)

x <- c("Apr-13", "May-14")
#add DD as 01
x <- paste("01",x,sep="-")

#result
dmy(x)

#output
#[1] "2013-04-01 UTC" "2014-05-01 UTC"
```